# consuming web service in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, soap

i want to use a web Service(WSDL) in my WPF App.

i have add it as a Service Reference to my app.

Code to call it is as :

```
ServiceReference1.WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoapClient soap = 
    new ServiceReference1.WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoapClient();

ServiceReference1.Request requestObj = new ServiceReference1.Request();
requestObj.UserID = "1001002_S1234534H";
requestObj.DomainName = "XXXX";
requestObj.MessageContent = "<PcpsChronicBalanceEnquiry>" +
                            "<Request>" +
                            "<PatientNric>S1234534H</PatientNric>" +
                            "<Year>2015</Year>" +
                            "<BillType>C</BillType>" +
                            "</PcpsChronicBalanceEnquiry>";

var ss = soap.Operation_1(requestObj);
```

But i dint get any response.

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoap">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoap1" />
            <binding      name="ISB_SAB_Orchestration_Orchestration_1_Port_SAB_RequestSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
      
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://u103-vw-bzap01.tst.cleo.sg:9320/ws/ISB_SAB_Interface_Ext_Proxy/ISB_SAB_Interface_Ext.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoap"
            contract="ServiceReference1.WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoap"
            name="WebService_ISB_SAB_Interface_ExtSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.9.34/ISB_SAB_Interface_Proxy/ISB_SAB_Orchestration_Orchestration_1_Port_SAB_Request.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ISB_SAB_Orchestration_Orchestration_1_Port_SAB_RequestSoap"
            contract="ServiceReference2.ISB_SAB_Orchestration_Orchestration_1_Port_SAB_RequestSoap"
            name="ISB_SAB_Orchestration_Orchestration_1_Port_SAB_RequestSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

it throws exception as

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at https://u103-vw-bzap01.tst.cleo.sg:9320/ws/ISB_SAB_Interface_Ext_Proxy/ISB_SAB_Interface_Ext.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

Please help to resolve.

Comment: You haven't called the web service even once. You are just creating a bunch of new objects. Normally, the service reference generated has a `...Client` class that has methods you can call. Probably your `soap` variable. Call some methods on it.

Comment: Thanks dude. after calling a method am getting There was no endpoint listening at....... , I couldn't access the server.Can you please explain me the steps to connect with server

Comment: Didn't you get the WSDL from said server?

Comment: yes i got and added it to the app too

Comment: To consume web service is it necessary to have IIS on local

Comment: You should post your current code, including the `web.config` or `app.config` file.

Comment: Hi, i have added full code and app.config too.please help to resolve

Comment: So... *is* there an endpoint listening at the given address? Can you get it's WSDL for example? By the way, your XML is not valid. You are missing a closing tag in your MessageContent.